# Vapour pressure and Raoults law

Tags: solutions, vapor-pressure

Suppose we take a binary ideal solution having components A and B ....  let's say that their mole fraction is 1/3 and 2/3 respectively (for simplicity)

Now ... We know that this solution will start evaporating untill a dynamic equilibrium is achieved ... And some molecules of A and some molecules of B from solution will break apart from solution and go into vapour phase .... Also the molecules breaking apart will be different for A and B(depending on which is more volatile)

Now **my **

In the expression of raoults law
what value we have to put in for  Xa(mole fraction of A) .... The initial one before dynamic equilibrium (1/3) or the final one after equilibrium is achieved (which will be different)

And if both the mole fractions are same then how come that is true??

Comment: The prior site search about the topic is the basic prerequisite for asking on most sites.